# Как собрать OpenSSL под Emscripten в Windows?

Tags: openssl, emscripten

Под windows тоже не понял как собрать, делаю так:
perl Configure VC-WIN32
nmake
получаю: NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1'
Но это не страшно - нашел готовые lib под Windows.

Исходники OpenSSL представляют собой адскую смесь из С и Perl. И как я понял нужно сначала сконфигурировать их с помощью perl под нужный компилятор, а потом уже собирать.

Вот тут дан замечательный совет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974738/how-to-link-openssl-with-emscripten
"Compile the two libraries : crypto and openssl with emscripten"
Как это сделать?

Вот похожий вопрос, но это как я понял под unix:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327290/linking-openssl-with-webassembly

Может быть так-же есть готовые? Подойдет ли эта библиотека собранная в unix для Emscripten под windows?